# An ORM framework for XML

Tags: c#, xml, orm, xml-serialization

I am always bound to write an XML serializer classes to save data to disk in my different applications that use XML files as a structured info storage.

Is there a tool that you can feed an example of an XML structure and it will generate a c-sharp class to work with such xml structure?

For example I want to work with XML store of "projects"

```xml
<projectsInfo>
    <projectTypes>
        <Type>super</Type>
        <Type>best</Type>
    </projectTypes>

    <projects>
        <project>
              <name>One</name>
              <p-type>best</p-type>
        </project>
    </projects>    
</projectsInfo>
```

And it would generate a Linq-to-XML enabled class to add/remote types and projects instances.

Maybe this is already a commonly solved solution I am just not aware of, or everyone is using a build-in XML serialization of memory objects?

Answer (score 1):

c# has the `XmlSerializer` class that is designed to serialise objects to XML files.
You can simply annotate your class with various attributes to format the XML. (eg `[XmlElement]`,`[XmlAttribute]` etc.)

Comment: Well, serializing single elements is ok, but will I be able to write `GetAllProjectsOfType(string type)` methods when the data is serialized using the built-in serializer?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an XSD you can generate it with the xsd.exe that you open in the visual studio command line.

More info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx

This will auto generate classes from an XSD, and it can generate an XSD from an XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate classes/schema based on your xml file using the XSD utility provided with visual studio. Once you have the class, you can use the XmlSerializer to serialzie / deserialize files into instances of class. LINQ will work with any property within the class which implements `IEnumerable<T>` (any collection).

With .net 4 you can also use the [dynamic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/19/dynamic-in-c-4-0-creating-wrappers-with-dynamicobject.aspx) keyword, to build a dynamic xml wrapper, but im not sure its too comfortable / usefull